# How to manipulate Json data from live website on a map through Spring MVC Web app, tell me at least which dependencies and maps I could use

Tags: json, spring-mvc, data-visualization

Please help me to know what I want to do. I want to build Spring MVC-based Web App which displays data on a map according to existing live data on a governmental site that is already in JSON format. How do I do it? How do I connect JSON data to my map and manipulate that data on the map, so that it is an interactive map? What are the tools you would suggest, The link to a JSON format data is below: http://www.stat.kg/en/opendata/category/112/json

Comment: if you want to build an interactive map i would suggest you to use map liberaries like leafletjs etc. also the data at the link you provided does not contain any longitude or lattitude information which is required to make layers on maping liberaries

Comment: Thank you so much if you hadn't answered I wouldn't even have thought about moments of longitude and latitude, god bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was a beginner at designing from scratch classes I didn't know how it is done. Now that I work and experienced the design process from scratch I can structurize this small JSON.

1. You can use the *PostGIS | Web GIS |GeoServer with Spring Boot*(Google it) to create interactive maps and geo-visualizations.
2. By looking at the JSON file provided you can create the class depending on the logic e.g. response can be one class that contains properties data, titles, units and have a class regions which has properties pk, priority, title_en, title_kg, title_ru, values. And regions class will just be saved in collection data property of response class. This is just simple first look solution.
3. In order to make it work with unfolding map just need to map with Map class the Regions class so that on map you could show region's data accordingly on the map layout.

Hope this helps somebody who had the same struggles as me at the beginning